# Getting "Failed assertion, no message given." as error when running Ruby Selenium Test Cases

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver to write tests, and the following code returns the error message "Failed assertion, no message given.":

```
product_name_error_message =  @driver.find_element(:tag_name => "span", :class => "error").text
assert product_name_error_message == "Product Name must be greater than 3 and less than 255 characters!"
```

Sorry, I'm a newbie to Ruby and I couldn't find any solutions for this error message on the web. I've checked with a browser, this text does appear on the page, and with the proper span tag and class. It's just that the selenium webdriver can't find this element, and throws this inconclusive error. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying what value is returned after you run your first line of code.

So

```
product_name_error_message =  @driver.find_element(:tag_name => "span", :class => "error").text
puts product_name_error_message
assert product_name_error_message == "Product Name must be greater than 3 and less than 255 characters!"
```

I reckon that variable does not hold that value anyways.

Also you could club all in one line -

```
verify { assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "span", :class => "error").text.include?(Product Name must be greater than 3 and less than 255 characters!"),"The text is present")}
```

Comment: But when I run the same code in Linux, it all works fine. Is this an issue with Windows? I asked a friend of mine to try out the same code on his Windows and got the same error. Linux works fine for him too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver returns unicode values from the webpages. Comparing regular string with unicode one might be the reason why the assertion in your code fails.

Another guess is trailing whitespaces in the element's text value.